# webcam not working on Dell Latitude 5500 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, dell, webcam, realtek

I've install Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Latitude 5500 laptop. The only thing that doesn't work is the webcam. I've found this guide by Dell:
[https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-uk/sln298412/a-guide-to-webcams-on-dell-notebook-and-desktop-pcs-with-ubuntu-operating-systems?lang=en][1]

I'm not able to find the USB ID for the integrated webcam. I can find the vendor id with lsusb -v:

```
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58fd Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x58fd 
  bcdDevice           86.16
  iManufacturer           3 
  iProduct                1 
  iSerial                 2 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0471
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    ** UNRECOGNIZED:  28 ff 42 49 53 54 00 01 06 16 10 00 00 00 00 00 01 17 f4 01 02 18 f4 01 03 19 f4 01 04 1a f4 01 05 1b f4 01 06 1c e8 03
```

lsusb returns:

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0451:8340 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58fd Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0451:82ff Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04ca:005d Lite-On Technology Corp. StoreJet Transcend
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0451:8342 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 047d:2048 Kensington Orbit Trackball with Scroll Ring
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg output:

```
   [    3.153060] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0bda:58fd)
[    3.161691] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Microsoft Extended Controls Uni was not initialized!
[    3.161693] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
[    3.161694] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[    3.161696] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[    3.161697] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[    3.161698] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    3.348081] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0bda:58fd)
[    3.350711] uvcvideo 1-6:1.2: Entity type for entity Microsoft Extended Controls Uni was not initialized!
[    3.350712] uvcvideo 1-6:1.2: Entity type for entity Extension 9 was not initialized!
[    3.350713] uvcvideo 1-6:1.2: Entity type for entity Extension 11 was not initialized!
[    3.350714] uvcvideo 1-6:1.2: Entity type for entity Camera 8 was not initialized!
[    3.350807] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Could I have some help finding the USB ID. Or, is there another way of getting the webcam working?

Comment: the USB ID is in the column next to the "ID" in the lsusb output (two hex mumbers separated by ":"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I cannot even see the device detected in lsusb, and the system journal is silent about uvc/UVC/Webcam.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Dell Latitude E5540.

Check if it's not a hardware issue

1. Reboot ubuntu 20.04 and on the black startup screen press f12
2. Under Other Options select Diagnostics
3. Under Dell ePSA,  select configurations TAB and check if microphone camera boot option = not Installed [if this is the case proceed to step 4.
4. Open the screen and check if the camera is connected correctly. In my case, it was disconnected.

---